# Remove counters from creature after an effect like fling

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-stack

Let's say I have a 3/3 creature with two +1/+1 counters in it making it a  5/5. I then use an ability or spell like [Fling](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fling) that sacrifices a creature to deal damage equal to the sacrificed creatures power. Can I then use [Ooze Flux](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ooze%20Flux) to remove the counters from the sacrificed creature to create my Ooze token? And if I can would Fling continue to do 5 damage or would it be reduced to 3?

Comment: Related: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/39633/can-a-flung-creature-that-is-destroyed-still-deal-damage

Answer (score 10):

**No, you cannot do that.**

Sacrificing the creature is a cost to cast Fling. Casting a spell includes paying its costs, so once you have finished casting it, by the time you can do anything in response, the creature is already dead.

Answer (score 3):

Using an effect like Ooze Flux you have two options:

1. Remove the counters before casting fling - thus doing less damage.
2. Fling with the counters still on - thus unable to move the counters.

Since sacrificing the creature is a cost to cast fling, there's no point where fling is on the stack, the damage it will do has been calculated, and the creature is still on the battlefield to be interacted with.

There are other ways to "save" those counters however - if you are flinging a creature with the Modular keyword, the creature will still have the counters for the purposes of Fling, but the counters will "move" when it dies because of the effect of Modular, or with a card like [The Ozolith](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=The%20Ozolith) which sees the creature having counters when it died and "moves" them onto itself.

Note, I use quotes around "save" and "move" because MtG doesn't really move counters between permanents much anymore - new counters are placed on the other permanent, this means that having both Modular and The Ozolith can allow you to get twice as many counters as the creature had before.